# Multiple countDown timers on a single page in a meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, timer, countdown

I am struggling to get multiple countdown timers displayed in a meteor app.

AuctionExpireIn is a date in the format - 2015-03-23T17:17:52.412Z.

Have a auctionItems collection , displaying 3 rows of auction items in auctionItem template.

While the target date is different for each of the auction items, what I am seeing is all the three rows have the same countdown timer . Apparently the session is not tied to each of the records and the same session value is being displayed for all the three rows.

How do I get different rows to display countdown timer based on the target data that each auction item document has?

Appreciate all the help.

```
Template.auctionItem.helpers({

AuctionExpireIn : function() {

                var target_date = new Date(this.AuctionExpireIn).getTime();
                //alert (target_date);
                // variables for time units
                var days, hours, minutes, seconds;



                // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
                setInterval(function( ) {

                        // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
                        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
                        var countdown ='';
                        // do some time calculations
                        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

                        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                        // format countdown string + set tag value
                        countdown= days + "d, " + hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";
                        Session.set ('countdown', countdown);
                }, 1000);

                return Session.get('countdown');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a spacebars helper using ReactiveVar or Session. This example outputs the current time every second.

```
Template.registerHelper('Timer', (options)->
  now = new Date()
  reactive = new ReactiveVar(now.getTime())

  Meteor.setInterval(()->
    now = new Date()
    reactive.set now.getTime()
  ,1000)

  return reactive.get()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tie each countdown timer to an instance of your auctionItem template. The below works as a proof-of-concept; each template will pick a random number from 1 to 10 and count down to 0. To apply it to your case, just replace the random number with the moment.js difference between this.AuctionExpireIn and new Date() (which I did not look up because I don't know it offhand).

```
Template.auctionItem.created = function(){
  var self = this;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  this.remaining = new ReactiveVar(num);
  this.interval = Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    var remaining = self.remaining.get();
    self.remaining.set(--remaining);
    if (remaining === 0){
      Meteor.clearInterval(self.interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

Template.auctionItem.helpers({
  remaining: function(){
    return Template.instance().remaining.get();
  }
});
```

One point I noticed from the efforts above is you don't want to try to set the counters from a helper; just get the counters from a helper.

Comment: Appreciate your reply . This seems like somewhat in the direction of what I need. Two things - 1st I have the AuctionExpirein which is only visible in the Template.auctionItem.helpers()  and not in the Template.auctionItem.created. So i am not able to calculate the exact countdown .

Comment: 2nd I do not want to decrement the counter as you have shown , If the AuctionExpire is some time in future , want to display time left like 2d:6hr:55sec and which will be reactive based on the current time .. and keep changing on the screen per each auction item

Comment: @Chansdad why can't you move AuctionExpireIn to the this context as a ReactiveVar?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for pointing in the right direction . Managed to solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the above is all of your current logic for your application, but based on what you have provided, the issue seems to be that you are using a single Session variable to keep track of the remaining time for three different auction items. If you need to use Session in order to keep track of your remaining times for the three different auction items, you should use three separate Session variables to do so, for example:

```
Session.set('auctionItemOne');
Session.set('auctionItemTwo');
Session.set('auctionItemThree');
```

But honestly, this is not the best way to go about solving this problem. Instead, I would recommend creating a simple template helper that takes in the end date/time for an auction item and outputs the appropriate string to describe the amount of time remaining. This can be easily accomplished with a library such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/). In order to implement this solution, do something like the following:

```
// Template
<template name="auctionItem">
    {{timeRemaining}}
</template>

// Template Helper
Template.auctionItem.helpers({
    timeRemaining: function() {
        // Call appropriate Moment.js methods

        // Return the string returned by Moment.js
    }
});
```

I hope that this helps point you in a better direction for how to handle your situation. Please let me know if you need any further explanation or assistance.

Comment: I originally tried to implement the way you suggested and that resulted in a static time remaining value. what I rather want is to display the counter that changes based on the time.now based on auction end date.  After a little research I started to use session variable which is reactive. I could not set the session based on the document Id which is like Session.set(docid) where docid is the id of the auction item. I was able to set session likeSession.set('234') .

Comment: I see. In that case then, I would suggest going the Session variable route and having a different session variable for each of your three auction items. This way, you can control the exact output of your template helper and keep the information for your auction items completely independent from eachother.

Comment: Now here is the issue,how do I set session variables dynamically? There is no use setting the statically as Session.set('row1'), session.set('row2') etc rather I want to set it dynamically as Session.set(myrowvariable) and retrieve it with session.get(myrowvariable) which Iam not able to do as session.set(myrowvariable) is not setting the session.

Comment: You could do something like use the auction item ID as your session variable key like so: `Session.set(auctionItemID, \* result of calculation function *\)`. This would allow you to uniquely store the time string for each of your auction items, and a reliable way of retrieving them as well.

Comment: Does not work. That is what I tried to do. Unless it is a string Session is not setting it. Session.set(auctionItemID, \*calculated value *\) does not work where as Session.set('1001', \* calculated value*\) works and sets the session '1001'

Comment: If you use the document ID from MongoDB for a given auction item, this ID should be a string, rather than an integer. Have you tried using the document ID, rather than a programatically-defined integer ID?

Comment: Try using reactive variables which are created for template instance so every template would have it's own timer. I'm on the phone tho so I can't give you code, but you should check it